# Why does MySQL hardcode the max depth of a JSON document?

Tags: mysql, json

I recently ran into the [ER_JSON_DOCUMENT_TOO_DEEP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_json_document_too_deep). I looked online for documentation, but couldn't find anything explaining why the tree depth was limited to 100 or how I could override that.

Then I looked around in the MySQL codebase and [discovered that the value had been hardcoded](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blame/4869291f7ee258e136ef03f5a50135fe7329ffb9/sql/json_syntax_check.cc#L80) to 100.

Why would you want to hardcode the depth of the JSON tree? It seems like something that should be configurable.

Comment: I'd guess that some of the code that implements JSON support uses recursion, and they wanted to put a limit on the depth of recursion. But that's just speculation.

Comment: If you have a good case for more than 100,  submit a enhancement request at bugs.mysql.com please.  Having a good use case will make your request stronger.